# Why doesn't it automatically generate method comments in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

In my Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates, I had "Automatically add comments for new methods and types" checked, but it doesn't create any default method comments for my newly created classes.

I configured something in my "Files" and "Types", and it is able to generate comments I want. but it doesn't generate default comments for my methods.

Answer (score 0):

In java -> Code style -> Code Templates -> Methods,

Comment: Not a good answer. This is more of a comment. consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer